# can a site.master page have its own site.master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

can you have it where one site master page itself has a site master page to allow layers of shared "base" code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when creating a master page, you can specify a master page for it.

(Also, you can name master pages whatever you want -> Temp.Master, master.master)

Comment: how do i refer to placeholder sections in the different master files?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to this very similar question may be helpful: [Are there nested master pages in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947134/are-there-nested-master-pages-in-asp-net-mvc) Yes, you can use nested master pages in MVC, as you can with "classic" ASP.Net.